# How to structure yacc code to support optional nonterminals

Tags: yacc, bison

What is the best way to model optional data in yacc? I have the following statement:

```
StmtBlock           :    '{' VariableDeclList StmtList '}' {  $$ = new StmtBlock($2, $3); }
                    ;
```

Both, VariableDeclList and StmtList are optional (epsilon) so I modeled them as follows:

```
VariableDeclList    :    VariableDeclList VariableDecl  { ($$=$1)->Append($2); }
                    |    { $$ = new List<VarDecl*>; }
```

and

```
StmtList            :    StmtList Stmt { ($$=$1)->Append($2); }
                    |    { $$ = new List<Stmt*>; }
                    ;
```

The only problem is when I think this causes shift/reduce conflicts. When I try to compile my code my y.ouput file has the following:

```
State 74 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
...
state 74

   38 StmtBlock: '{' VariableDeclList . StmtList '}'
   39 VariableDeclList: VariableDeclList . VariableDecl

    T_Bool        shift, and go to state 2
    T_Int         shift, and go to state 3
    T_Double      shift, and go to state 4
    T_String      shift, and go to state 5
    T_Identifier  shift, and go to state 8

    T_Identifier  [reduce using rule 18 (Epsilon)]
    $default      reduce using rule 18 (Epsilon)

    VariableDecl  go to state 80
    Variable      go to state 13
    Type          go to state 34
    Epsilon       go to state 81
    StmtList      go to state 82
...
```

Is there a more proper way to model this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, this will cause shift/reduce conflicts if a *Stmt* and a *VariableDecl* can't be distinguished by their first token -- in your example a `T_Identifier` might begin either.  There are a number of things you can try:

- combine the two lists into a *VariableDeclOrStmtList* which can contain either *Stmt* or *VariableDecl* intermixed in any way.  This is more general than what you have, so you'll need a post-check to ensure that there are no *VariableDecls* after the first *Stmt*
- Use more lookahead to determine the difference -- either use bison's GLR mode, or something like [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc) that can defer deciding whether something is a *Stmt* or *VariableDecl* until it has seen enough to decide
- Use different tokens at the beginning of these constructs to unambiguously differentiate them.  These can be either real tokens in your language, or synthetic tokens that the lexer inserts based on some additional context (which means basically doing more lookahead in the lexer).

**edit**

For the first suggestion, you'll have a rule like:

```
VarDeclOrStmtList : VarDeclOrStmtList VariableDecl { ($$=$1)->Append($2); }
                  | VarDeclOrStmtList Stmt         { ($$=$1)->Append($2); }
                  | { $$ = new List<Node *>; }
                  ;
```

where `Node` is a common base class of `VarDecl` and `Stmt`.  Then, in your StmtBlock action, call a function that goes through the `List<Node *>`, splitting it into a `List<VarDecl *>` and `List<Stmt *>` and giving an error message if it is not well-formed.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the suggestions. Could you point me in the right direction for how you would go about doing the post-check in your first suggestion?